# Uncaught ReferenceError: sendEmail is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Probably something simple going on here, but I have to attend to it before I attend to the PHP stuff. I'm going to try to use PHPMailer this time.

Also I've been trying to learn how to send a form on localhost for about a week now. Now I'm going to try to to incorporate PHPMailer.  I had originally spent some time enabling a sites available to point to another folder, installing and testing PHP and installing msmtp on debian, even sent a test email with PHP, via command line but I haven't gotten one form to submit right yet and it's a :p

Also when working on forms before I made a couple changes to my php.ini files one on apache dir and one on cli dir, I think I uncommented some stuff and I hope it wont interfere with the what I'm trying to do.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Contact</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style type="text/css">
        input, textarea {
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top:100px;">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" align="center">
                <input id="name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control">
                <input id="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
                <input id="subject" placeholder="Subject" class="form-control">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="body" placeholder="Email Body"></textarea>
                <input type="button" onclick="sendEmail()" value="Send an Email" class="btn btn-primary"></type>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function sendEmail() {
            console.log('sending...');
            var name = $("#name");
            var email = $("#email");
            var subject = $("#subject");
            var body = $("#body");

            if (isNotEmtpy(name) && isNotEmpty(email) && isNotEmpty(subject)  && isNotEmpty(body)) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'sendEmail.php',
                    method: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        name: name.val(),
                        email: email.val(),
                        body: body.val()
                    }, success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response)
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    function isNotEmpty(caller)  {
        if (caller.val()) == "") {
            caller.css('border', 1px solid red');
            return false;
        } else
            caller.css('border', '');

        return true;
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
RAW Paste Data
```

Comment: You have a syntax error at `if (caller.val()) == "") {` and `caller.css('border', 1px solid red');`, which is breaking your full javascript. Also, `isNotEmtpy` is misspelled

Comment: thank you so much aynber, i think you called it correct, thanks for your time and knowledge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendEmail() {
        console.log('sending...');
        var name = $("#name");
        var email = $("#email");
        var subject = $("#subject");
        var body = $("#body");

        if (isNotEmpty(name) && isNotEmpty(email) && isNotEmpty(subject)  && isNotEmpty(body)) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'sendEmail.php',
                method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    name: name.val(),
                    email: email.val(),
                    body: body.val()
                }, success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response)
                }
            });
        }
    }

    function isNotEmpty(caller) {
        if (caller.val() === "") {
            caller.css('border', '1px solid red');
            return false;
        } else {
            caller.css('border', '');
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

I checked. Work fine.

Comment: thank you so much, I looked over the differences and it looks like I was getting held up at the inNotEmpty function, I have no experience with javascript and wasn't even aware of the === operator or the ability of that to interrupt the send mail function.  Anways thanks a lot! it was super kind of you to reprint the code with corrections.